Using incopmlete & unsorted database column in schedule block
I want to use an incopmlete & unsorted (date is not increasing) database column x in a schedule block to create agents. I also need the other values in the same row because they get connected as parameters in the specific agent. These rows which have an emplty cell in column x should not create an agent. I also use the database in an other schedule block, so there the database should be sorted based on an other column.
How can I sort the database based on column x?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Create a view and make it run an SQL statement that ORDER BY your data as you like.

great, pls upvote useful replies, helps future users with similar issues
